# xcode install: User has disabled system data installation

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qVDT.png)

When I install xcode with App Store,the console of mac show inform on the image.What should I do?

I can install xcode normaly.

Is this normal, and if not, what should I do.

---

Xcode installing of 979 of 1000, and it never rise again.

Here is the progress of application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMCFC.png)

Thanks for any help!